# PHP Remote Host Window file name highlighting?

Tags: phpstorm

Sometimes the file names in the Remote Host window are highlighted in green.  What does it indicate?

I just downloaded the new version 6.0.2  In the Remote Host Window, pull down list of hosts, some of the hosts are also tinted green.  For any of these, all the files are tinted green.  Once gain, what does it indicate?

Comment: Have you got a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are speaking of directories and files that are included to be synchronized and indexed. i.e. Project Root, Excluded from Download, Resource Root, Excluded from Indexing.

[image: Choose Remote Path]